# Tableau 2019 Forgot Password Link auto-redirects to login screen

Tags: tableau-api, change-password

having recently upgraded to Tableau 2019.2.4, I attempted to implement the self-service "forgotten you password" link from the signin page.

We are using Local Authentication.

```
   tsm set features.PasswordReset true
```

successfully displays the "Forgotten Your Password" link on the Tableau login screen for the user to click on.

During testing, test users clicked on "forgotten your password" link from login screen, entered their username as prompted and subsequently received an email containing the password reset link.

BUT when the test users click on the password reset link or alternatively copy the full URL given in the email into their browser, they are immediately redirected to the login screen.

i.e. they get stuck in a loop of login screen->click on forgot password link->enter username->open email->click on link in email->login screen....

Web people have ruled out web filtering issues as the cause.

Have searched online forums and documentation and shed no light.

Anyone else come across this? How did you fix it. All help gratefully received.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so turns there was a basic error in the configuration settings when our initial install was done a couple of years ago - when the password reset facility was not available and we weren't generating emails for other purposes either .... so although basic, it took a while to trace and there was no online documentation on this (apparently there is now/shortly will be) so perhaps of use to other people so posting.

DETAILS:

We had set the Tableau Server URL up in our config settings to be the URL users use to access our Tableau Content, namely:

```
   http://<tableau server name>/#/signin.
```

This led to a URL of

```
   http://<tableau server name>/#/signin/#/passwordreset
```

being sent to users ... hence they always landed on

```
  http://<tableau server name>/#/signin
```

rather than the password reset screen for obvious reasons.

Once we set up the Tableau Server URL up in our config settings as the server name URL only i.e.

```
   http://<tableau server name>
```

the correct link was generated, namely:

```
   <http://<tableau server name>/#/resetPassword/bigLongSecureHashKeyIdentifier
```

and it worked a treat.